# Ansible - Undefined Variable In Shell Command

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have the following playbook, which should just pull package names and versions and print to debug:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Get current versions of packages
    shell: "yum list installed {{ packages }} | grep vim-enhanced | awk '{print $1 $2}'"
    var:
      packages:
      - vim-enhanced
      - nss-pem
    register: packages_installed
    changed_when: False

  - name: Print packages installed
    debug:
      var: packages_installed
```

When run, I receive the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'packages' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/patching/patching.yaml': line 4, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n  - name: Get current versions of packages\n    ^ here\n"}
```

I'm still fairly new to this so there is most likely something basic I'm missing, but I have not found any articles at this point to resolve.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two problems.

First, it needs to be `vars` and not `var`.

```
- name: Get current versions of packages
  shell: ...
  vars:     # <---
    packages:
    - vim-enhanced
    - nss-pem
```

Second, `packages` is a list, which gets interpolated as `[u'vim-enhanced', u'nss-pem']` into the shell command. That's probably not what you want.
Also your grep for `vim-enhanced` makes no sense then.

Comment: You got it - and thank you for the information! I missed adding to the grep for nss-pem, but overall was making it a bit more complex than it needed to be. I changed it to "vars" and switched to "packages: vim-enhanced nss-em" to format the yum command correctly.